# Ionic 4 - Screen Orientation(landscape) does not work

Tags: cordova, screen-orientation, ionic4

I am new on Ionic 4 and I am trying to set the screen orientation to landscape and referring to docs this is what I am doing:

```
...
import {ScreenOrientation} from '@ionic-native/screen-orientation';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {

  constructor(
    private platform: Platform,
    private splashScreen: SplashScreen,
    private statusBar: StatusBar,
    private screenOrientation: ScreenOrientation,
  ) {
    this.initializeApp();
  }

  initializeApp() {
    this.screenOrientation.lock(ScreenOrientation.ORIENTATIONS.LANDSCAPE);
    ...
  }
}
```

and during compilation, I get this error:

> [ng] ERROR in src/app/app.component.ts(24,33): error TS2345: Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OrientationLockType'.

and on browser console:

> Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for AppComponent: ([object Object], [object Object], [object Object], ?).
>       at syntaxError (compiler.js:2426) []
>   ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a problem in the injection for the fourth parameter, 
did you correctly install the screen orientation plugin?

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-screen-orientation
npm install @ionic-native/screen-orientation
```

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-screen-orientation/

If this doesn't work you should try this way ( withoud the import and injection )

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-screen-orientation
```

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-screen-orientation/

Also, if you want to force landscape orientation for the whole application it is possibile to add a preference in config.xml

```
<preference name="orientation" value="landscape" />
```

I've tested it and it works in android platform 7.1.4

Answer (score 6):

you use ionic V4, please see the doc, import correct things.

```
import { ScreenOrientation } from '@ionic-native/screen-orientation/ngx';
```

not

```
import {ScreenOrientation} from '@ionic-native/screen-orientation';
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to add `ScreenOrientation` to the providers array in the module using the plugin.

For example in `app.module.ts`

Answer (score 1):

providers array in the module using the plugin.

```
    providers: [
    ScreenOrientation
 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me (Ionic 5). Inside your page.module, import dependency:

```
import { ScreenOrientation } from '@ionic-native/screen-orientation/ngx';
```

and provide to the module:

```
 providers: [
    ScreenOrientation, 
    ...]
```